# CodeSandbox.io <img> tag not loading image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, codesandbox

I have been trying add an image using the `<img> tag` on `CodeSandbox.io`. However, every time I try to add it, it doesn't show and just defaults to the `alt` tag (Displays Mountain).

I am trying to load an image in the same folder as the file in which this JS file is contained.

Below is the code which generates the HTML

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <navbar className="navbar">
      <div>
        <img src="business-landing-page-template-with-photo_52683-19539.jpg" alt="Mountain"/>
      </div>
    </navbar>
  )
```

Can someone please tell me how to get the image to load.

Comment: Is "business-landing-page-template-with-photo_52683-19539.jpg" in the public folder?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with my last comment. No it is not in public folder. It is in a seperate folder called src. This JavaScript file is located at src/components, and my image is located at src/img

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If in the public folder, use file path relative to it, i.e. `public/img/image.jpg`, otherwise, if the source image is in your component directories, you use `require` and relative path:

Given component in `src/components` and image is in `src/img`

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <navbar className="navbar">
      <div>
        <img
          src={require("../img/business-landing-page-template-with-photo_52683-19539.jpg")}
          alt="Mountain"
        />
        // or in public
        <img
          src="src/img/business-landing-page-template-with-photo_52683-19539.jpg"
          alt="cat"
        />
      </div>
    </navbar>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit use local image]

Comment: What does require do? Apologies, I am new to JS. Why does it work?

Comment: what if images are dynamically uploaded?

Comment: @AwesomeGuy Honestly I wish a had a decent answer for that question, but it's just the way to specify local image src urls. The other option is to import it at the top of the file and use directly, i.e. `import image from './business-landing-page-template-with-photo_52683-19539.jpg', then `<img src={image}...`

Comment: On codesandbox, can you point it to a png that's hosted on another website? src="http://someimagesite.com/myimg.png" ?

Comment: @MattoMK Do you mean like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/point-to-a-png-that-is-hosted-on-another-website-t46bd If so, then yes, you can.

Comment: @DrewReese lol yes! I tried that and it must have been a different type of url because it didn't work. It was from google images. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @DrewReese do you know if it's possible on codesandbox to do a file upload (input type= file) and save the result in the public folder? I know you can do FileReader.readAsDataUrl, but how to put the result into the public folder on codesandbox and then reference it?

Comment: @MattoMK That I don't know off the top of my head. Codesandbox runs in an iframe (AFAIK) so has some cross-site/domain restrictions. Seems like a good candidate for another SO question; someone else may have an answer for you more quickly than I could research it.