# Unable to import image in Reactjs returning error Module not found: Can't resolve

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component located in "projectfolder/src/pages/Home.js":-

```
import React from "react";
import MenuButton from "../components/Home/MenuButton";
import menuicon from "images/menuicon.png";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <MenuButton title="home ">
          <img src={menuicon} />
        </MenuButton>
        <MenuButton title="account" />
        <MenuButton title="create new" />
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <div className="signin-btns"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am trying to import an image file "menu-icon.png" which is located in "projectfolder/public/images".

I tried to import it using the following imports :-

1. import menuicon from "images/menu-icon.png" returned the following error :-

> ./src/pages/Home.js Module not found: Can't resolve
>   'images/menu-icon.png' in 'C:\Users\AHMAD\project\src\pages'

2. import menuicon from "/images/menu-icon.png";

> ./src/pages/Home.js Module not found: You attempted to import
>   /images/menu-icon.png which falls outside of the project src/
>   directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

3. import menuicon from "../../images/menu-icon.png";

> ./src/pages/Home.js Module not found: You attempted to import
>   ../../images/menu-icon.png which falls outside of the project src/
>   directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

I am using the ReactJS version : "^16.13.1" with "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473591/codesandbox-io-img-tag-not-loading-image/61473767#61473767

Comment: where is the images folder relative to the src folder?

Comment: @ehab the images folder C:\Users\AHMAD\project\public\images and src folder C:\Users\AHMAD\project\src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting the image in `projectfolder/public/images` it is outside your src directory. You won't be able to import it that way. You could do either of the following to resolve this:

- Move your image into `projectfolder/src/images` and `import menuicon from './images/menu-icon.png'`
- Leave it in public and remove the import statement. Instead use it like this: `<img src='images/menu-icon.png' />`